# Given a node Burn the binary tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to implement the given question [enter link description here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/burn-the-binary-tree-starting-from-the-target-node/) but not getting the desired output what is the problem with my program. Programmatically I am trying to find if the target no exists in left or right subtree , if it exists in left subtree return 1 from left side and push its children to queue and similarly for right tree.

```
Node root = new Node(1);
root.left = new Node(2);
root.right = new Node(3);
root.left.left = new Node(4);
root.left.right = new Node(5);
root.right.left = new Node(6);
root.right.right = new Node(7);
static Queue<Node> q=new LinkedList<Node>()
    burnTheNodes(root,2);
    int size=q.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        Node curr=q.remove();
        System.out.println(curr.data);
    }
     
private static int burnTheNodes(Node root,int num) {
    
    if(root==null) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(root.data==num) {
            System.out.println(root.data);
            if(root.left!=null) {
                q.add(root.left);
            }
            if(root.right!=null) {
                q.add(root.right);
            }
            return 1;
        }
    int a=burnTheNodes(root.left, num);
    if(a==1) {
        int size=q.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            Node curr=q.remove();
            System.out.print(curr.data+"-");
            if(curr.left!=null) {
                q.add(curr.left);
            }
            if(curr.right!=null) {
                q.add(curr.right);
            }
        }
        
        if(root.right!=null) {
            q.add(root.right);
        }
        System.out.println(root.data);
        return 1;
    }
    
    int b=burnTheNodes(root.right, num);
    if(b==1) {
        int size=q.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
            Node curr=q.remove();
            System.out.println(curr.data);
            if(curr.left!=null) {
                q.add(curr.left);
            }
            if(curr.right!=null) {
                q.add(curr.right);
            }
        }
        
        if(root.left!=null) {
            q.add(root.left);
        }
        System.out.println(root.data);
        return 1;
    }
    return 1;
    
}
```

Output is- It is missing nodes 6 and 7.
2
4-5-1
3

Comment: `q` is not declared.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out but I missed that while pasting the code here it is not the actual issue , the issue is somewhere in the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the final loop in `main`, you don't *add* children to the queue, like you do in similar loops in `burnTheNodes`.

You should really continue the process as long as there are entries in the queue, and keep adding entries as long as the extracted node has children.